# If/or statement throwing error in php 5.3.10

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements, version, conditional-operator

I have an `if` statement which is throwing a `syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE` error and I have no idea why.

The code:

```
<?php if($contentTop || $contentLeft || $contentCenter || $contentRight): ?>
  <div>a bunch of html</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The variable contains eiter an empty string or a bunch of html.

I have tried changing the `||` to `or` but it doesn't seem to change anything. neither does opening and closing the `if` statement with curly brackets. It only seems to work when i only have one variable in the statement. I have also tried using `!empty($contentTop)` to check the variables.

The server is running PHP version `5.3.10-1ubuntu3.26` but as far as I can see, that should not change anything regarding `if` statements

EDIT:

On request of the full markup:

```
<?php 
$contentTop = get_field('section2new_content');
$contentLeft = get_field('section2new_left');
$contentCenter = get_field('section2new_center');
$contentRight = get_field('section2new_right');


if( $contentTop || $contentLeft || $contentCenter || $contentRight ): ?>

    <div class="bbh-inner-section teaser-3-col" id="section2temp">
        <?php if($contentTop): ?>
            <div class="grid-container top">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <?php echo $contentTop; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($contentLeft || $contentRight || $contentCenter): ?>
            <div class="grid-container bottom">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 left">
                        <?php echo $contentLeft; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 center">
                        <?php echo $contentCenter; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 right">
                        <?php echo $contentRight; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

As i noticed myself i have second `if / ||` statement further down, which seems to work fine. It's also not that I mistakenly inserted a wrong type of space or whateever, I have manually rewritten the code multiple times

Comment: Your code looks fine. May be issue is before if statement. check line above the if

Comment: Can you show entire page code

Comment: Error shows the exact line of the initial `if` statement. Also I updated the question with my full markup.

Answer (score 1):

I tried @Poiz answer which worked. Being a bit suspicious i tried my own original code again, which now also worked. Human error once again. Maybe it was some illegal version of a space or tab.

Comment: Thanks @Emil Østervig for your Openness and Sincerity... The Goal here is that you find the optimal or even Best Solution to your Problem (how & from whom are only secondary considerations). And again another thanks for confirming that the suggested option below may not be the Best but doesn't deserve a Down-Vote either. **Keep up that Sincere + Open Heart for it is worth far much more that the Greatest Head ever.** Cheers Mate ☝️✌️

Answer (score 0):

Would you be open to trying something a little odd? Anyways, it is essentially the same thing you did except that we turned the `if` Statements into Ternary Operations. This is because like You said; you've tried almost all combinations of `if` without success, except when only one Condition is supplied.... The Idea here is simply to crunch down the Line that does the main Comparison to a single, simple Boolean Value, which can then be used within the Subsequent `if`. Perhaps this works for you since your Magical `if` works only in the Case you have but One Condition to test for...

```
    <?php $state = ($contentTop || $contentLeft || $contentCenter || $contentRight) ? true : false; ?>
    <?php if($state): ?>
        <div>a bunch of html</div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It's always good to see an alternative, how odd it might be. I tried your code, which worked. I then tried replacing it with my original code, which somehow now also worked. Now I'm left questioning my sanity.
I never actually thought of saving a conditional state like this, but i'm sure i can use it sometime where i have a lot of repetition or whatever.